# Extracting a part of String using grep/sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have a file in linux with similar entries as below

```
dn: CN=HP_NetworkSupport,OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM
dn: CN=Review users,OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM
```

I would like to extract only the CN information, till the first ,
for ex:

```
> HP_NetworkSupport
> Review users
```

in the above case to another file.

What would be command for doing the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"=|," '{print $2}' file
HP_NetworkSupport
Review users
```

or

```
awk -F[=,] '{print $2}' file
HP_NetworkSupport
Review users
```

Set the delimiter to `,` or `=`, then print second field.

---

To handel field with comma within, you should use a parser for LDAP, but this should work.

```
echo file
dn: CN=HP_NetworkSupport,OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM
dn: CN="Review, users",OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM

awk -F"CN=|,OU" '{print $2}' file
HP_NetworkSupport
Review, users
```

Answer (score 21):

This is one way with [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
grep -Po '(?<=CN=)[^,]*' file > new_file
```

It gets all text from `CN=` (not included) until it finds a comma `,`. The idea of `[^,]*` is to fetch any character that is not a comma.

#### Test

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=CN=)[^,]*' file
HP_NetworkSupport
Review users
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it will fail for cases like `CN="Smith, John",OU="My Organization"`

Comment: Yes, but the input is not double quotes surrounded.

Comment: Well, this is part of software engineering job - predict what customers would use. And they most likely will

Comment: I know, but the input and the explanation does not show that. What if the parameters are not in the `CN, OU, DC` order? It would fail on your answer.

Comment: Granted, for many regex questions correct answer is NOT regex, but proper parser

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand it.

Comment: I mean that this is one nice example that to answer this question 100% correctly one must use LDAP parser. Technically, LDAP CN or OU *could* include text `CN=blah` (probably quoted) inside of it. How's that? This is similar to premise that you cannot use regex to parse XML.

Comment: Yes, I agree :) In fact I wasn't aware that this was a piece of LDAP config file. Let's see if our attempts are enough for the requirements, cheers!

Comment: Good solution is `GNU Grep` is available +1. To fixed @mvp criticism you could do include positive lookbehind `grep -Po '(?<=CN=).*(?=,OU=)' file`

Comment: Thanks @sudo_O! I will not update my answer, as the accepted one is not using it, so the OP may have enough with the simple comma checking. Anyway, thanks for teaching again! :)

Comment: Thank you for providing http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html link.

Comment: I'm curious, if you're searching for HTML or XML tags, would you need to escape the characters like this? `grep -Po '(?<=\<string name\=")[^"]*'`

Comment: @DavidKennedy give it a try ;-) I tried and my GNU grep says it is not necessary: `grep -Po '(?<=<hola>).*(?=</hola>)' <<< "<hola>adeu</hola>"` returns "adeu" without a problem. Of course, you can escape every single character, but this one is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*CN=([^,]*),.*/\1/' inputfile
HP_NetworkSupport
Review users
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/CN=([^\,]*),/)' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
dn: CN=HP_NetworkSupport,OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM
dn: CN=Review users,OU=groups,DC=HDFCSLDM,DC=COM
> perl -lne 'print $1 if(/CN=([^\,]*),/)' temp
HP_NetworkSupport
Review users
>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o 'CN=[^,]*' data | sed 's/^CN=//'
```

The grep command extracts CN=*blahblahblah* by finding 'CN=' followed by anything that is not a comma.  Then the sed command deletes 'CN=', leaving just the *blahblahblah*.  Another way of doing it is

```
grep -o 'CN=[^,]*' data | tail -c +4
```

where the tail commands excludes the first 3 characters, which would be 'CN='

Here it is via a Lua script invoked at the shell:

```
<data lua -e 'for s in io.lines() do m = string.match(s, "CN=([^,]*)"); if m then print(m) end end'
```

Being restricted to one line, it is less clear, of course, than if it were on multiple lines.

Note that the input redirection from the file named "data" is written **before** the command rather than after, which is uncommon but it works, and I think makes more sense conceptually.  This has nothing to do with Lua, it is shell syntax.

The Lua match pattern "CN=([^,]*)" is very similar to an extended regex--the parentheses denote a capture pattern in order to exclude the "CN=".

Lua does not use regular expressions, but a similar system.  See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Pipe it through this command:

```
sed -E "s/.*CN=(.+?),OU=.*/\\1/g"
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I think that `sed` can't use non-greedy quantifiers and parentheses must be escaped to do grouping.