# Regex Search after a variable length text

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need regex for extracting the text from the following tag:
I am using Python & BeautifulSoup

```
    <h4 style="color:#000000; line-height:20px; font-size:18px; margin-left:22px;
 overflow:auto; content:inherit; padding:10px; font-family:"Book Antiqua", 
Palatino, serif;">THE TEXT TO BE EXTRACTED IS HERE</h4></div><br /></div>
```

I tried the following:

```
stylecontent = 'color:#000000; line-height:20px; font-size:18px; margin-left:22px;
     overflow:auto; content:inherit; padding:10px; font-family:"Book Antiqua", 
    Palatino, serif;'

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read(), "lxml")

scrap_soup = soup.findAll('h4', {'style': stylecontent})
```

but It doesn't works always as the website keeps changing `stylecontent`.
Now I want to use regex:

```
soup.find_all(re.compile("some_foo_regex")):
```

I am interested in that `some_foo_regex`.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool/language are you using ? BTW this HTML is incorrect (look at the quotes)

Comment: Which language you were using. [Instead of regex you can simply use DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: See what HTML parsers exist for the language you are using. HTML and regular expressions do not go well together.

Comment: Use a parser, not a regex. What if you have an attribute like `someAttr=">fail</h4>"` ?

Comment: This one may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242661/extracting-a-part-of-string-using-grep-sed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a regex question and OP didn't precise any tool, language, or regex flavour.

Comment: I am using Python and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Please show your beautifulsoup related code.

Comment: @stribizhev Updated the question with code. Thanks.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yeah, the HTML may be wrong, but it's not my code, It's in the website that I am trying to scrap.

Comment: What is the constant expression? How can you identify the `h4` tag? Only when you know a pattern can you use a regex. Maybe the parent tag is known? What about getting all `div`s with `h4` and then checking some other condition?

Comment: @stribizhev Constant thing is: `<h4 style="foo_keeps_changing"> GET THIS TEXT </h4>`
I want all the text in h4 tag which has style element.

Comment: What about `h4_list = soup.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name == "h4" and len(tag.attrs) == 1 and tag["style"])`?

Comment: Or, `h4_tags = soup.find_alll('h4', attrs = {'style' : True}) \n for result in h4_tags: \n
    if len(result.attrs) == 1: \n
        print result`

Comment: @stribizhev 
Thanks! that gets me all the h4 tags with style element. Is there a way to get the text from these tags? Also can you add as answer so that I can Upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get all the `h4` tags that have only one attribute `style` with

```
h4_tags = soup.find_all('h4', attrs = {'style' : True}) # Get all H4 tags with style attribute
for result in h4_tags:
    if len(result.attrs) == 1:                          # Print if it is the only attribute
        print result.contents                           # Print tag text contents
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the text from these tags? Also My upvote doesn't works as I need to have atleast 15 reputation.
BTW, I also get tags which have other tags including style.

Comment: Doesn't `result.contents` print the contents? You have 15 rep now, BTW :) Also, what about the lambda solution: `h4_list = soup.find_all(lambda tag:tag.name == "h4" and len(tag.attrs) == 1 and tag["style"]) \n for result in h4_list: \n print result.contents`?

Comment: `h4_tags = soup.find_all('h4', attrs = {'style' : True})` gives me all tags I need and few extra, but running that loop gives me only one result.

Comment: That gives me a `KeyError: 'style'`

Comment: Thanks for letting know.