# how to grep and redirect the mac address alone without its prefix & suffix to a file for ifconfig command?

Tags: unix, grep

i have pasted the output of ifconfig command, and wanted to redirect the mac address(00:e0:4c:68:00:26) to a file from the entire output.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:00:26
          inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:26/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:4546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70055 TX bytes:1595889
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a part of String using grep/sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242661/extracting-a-part-of-string-using-grep-sed)

Comment: its not a duplicate, if you feel so can you provide using the solution mentioned in the question directed

Comment: First, find the according line with grep, then replace it using sed.

Comment: As you have included a good sample set of data, here is a close approximation that may help. `ifconfig| sed '/HWaddr/{s/^.*HWaddr //}'`. If you want ot know how it works, take the time to go thru [The Grymoire's Sed Tutoria](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) . This sort of Q gets asked and answered regularly, So please 1. search more carefully for possible solutions to your problem, 2. include references to that research in your Q, 3. read [help] and [mcve] before posting more Q here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I've stored the output of ifconfig in a variable `a`:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ echo $a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:68:00:26
          inet addr:192.168.10.1  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe68:26/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:4546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:70055 TX bytes:1595889

mayankp@mayank:~/$ echo $a| awk -F" " '{print $5}'|head -1 > 'mac_addr.txt'
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat mac_addr.txt 
00:e0:4c:68:00:26
```

Let me know if it works.